# When I'm trying to ./configure qbittorrent it says couldn't find qmake but I already have qmake

Tags: linux, qt, qmake, configure

Okay so I'm trying to install qbittorrent on my linux. I installed pkg-config I installed libtorrent and then I wrote ./configure on the terminal and it says

```
checking for Qt5 qmake >= 5.5.1... not found
configure: error: Could not find qmake
```

but I already have it installed. I reinstalled it 4-5 times but nothing changed.

And when I wrote `QTDIR=/usr/share/qt5 qmake --version`
 to the terminal it says `QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
so it's not about me using an older version of qmake it's late latest one.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: ok I did that thanks.